# how to remove map markers on setInterval refresh (js)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

Guys need a bit of help with google maps, I'm creating a tracking web app using MySQL DB coordinates, the tracking works well so far except the google map markers keep repeating when refreshed, I have set the map marker refresh using a setInterval function for every 5 seconds(for testing). I've tried clearoverlays() methods and remove map markers method(from google sample) but doesn't work. Appreciate your help, thank you

```
    <script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="KEY"8&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        setInterval(function () {  
           BindMarker();
        }, 5000);

        var customIcons = {
            blue: { icon: 'blue48.png'},  
        };

        var marker;
        var map = null;
        var infoWindow = null;
        function load() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.4370993, 110.3387572),
                zoom:15,
            });
            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; 
           
        }

        function BindMarker() { 
            downloadUrl('maps1.php', function (data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                    var icon = customIcons["blue"] || {}; 
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon,
                        shadow: icon.shadow
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            });
        }
        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.önreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status); }
            };
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }
        function doNothing() { }
</script>
```

*The functions I tried are given below( I called the remove overlays function, remove markers and also the delete markers function before BindMarker() inside the setInterval function so that it would remove the markers before binding new markers*

```
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { markers[i].setMap(map); }
  }

  function clearMarkers() {setMapOnAll(null); }
   
  function deleteMarkers() {clearMarkers(); markers = [];}


  function clearOverlays() {
    while(markers.length) { markers.pop().setMap(null); }
  markers.length = 0;
 }
```

Comment: This: "_I've tried ...  and ... but doesn't work._" - needs clarification. Show us what you tried, demonstrate what doesn't work.

Comment: @RandyCasburn edited post, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've confounded the examples, which your attempted code shows verbatim and what your code is actually doing.

It the sample code you're drawing from, the variable `markers` is an array of Google Map marker objects. So this code makes sense in that regard:

`function deleteMarkers() {clearMarkers(); markers = [];}`

But, your code is not creating an array of those objects. Your code does not have a variable named `markers` that is accessible outside of the `downloadUrl()` function. The variable `markers` does show up inside that function, but it contains an HTMLCollection element - not an array of markers.

To fix this you need to create an array named `markers` right after the variable name `marker` is created.

Then, within the `for` loop, just after you create the `marker` push that marker on to the `markers` array. You will also have to rename the existing `markers` variable to something more appropriate like `markerElements`.

Now, the `deleteMarkers()` function will work as expected.

Comment: thank you so much for the help,
 I corrected the code as you suggested and used clearOverlays() function inside my setInterval, works perfectly now